# Ember js: retrieving all documents from couchdb

Tags: ember.js

Well I am new to ember js and i am stuck at a place. I wanted to know how can one use ember-cli-sofa to retrieve all the documents at once? Well I am using couchdb as backend and ember-cli-sofa helps to interact with database.Please give any tips how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine without using models,

```
let db = store.get('db.main.documents');
db.all({ include_docs: true }); // => Promise
db.view('ddocName', 'viewName', { include_docs: true }); // => Promise
```

`db.all` calls `_all_docs` while `db.view` calls `/_design/<ddoc>/_view/<view>`

Comment: Thank you for that solution